# R: Using Summarize() accross() and where() with regular expressions

Tags: r, grepl, summarize

I have the following dataset:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age Obs_A Obs_B Obs_C
1  1       male   90 0 0 0
1  2       male   91 0 0 0
1  3       male   92 1 1 0
2  1       female  87 0 1 1
2  2       female  88 0 1 0
2  3       female  89 0 0 1
3  1       male  50 0 1 0
3  2       male  51 1 0 0
3  3       male  52 0 0 0
4  1       female  54 0 1 0
4  2       female  55 0 1 0
4  3       female  56 0 1 0"
```

I want to combine `summarize` with regular expressions (`grepl`) in order to reformat the variables that start with `Obs` (e.g. take the median) while do other operations for other variables. For example something like this:

```
TTE <- TTE %>%
      group_by(id, across(where(is.character))) %>%
      summarise(id = first(id), sex = first(sex), 
                Age = mean(Age), across(where(grepl("Obs")), mean), across(where(is.numeric), max)) %>%
      ungroup
```

Nonetheless, I get the following error:

```
x argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Any idea on how to use `summarize()`, `across()`, `where()` and `grepl()` in a consistent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `dplyr` you can use tidyselect function to select columns in `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

TTE %>%
  group_by(id, across(where(is.character))) %>%
  summarise(Age = mean(Age), 
            across(starts_with('Obs'), mean), 
            across(where(is.numeric), max)) %>%
  ungroup 

#     id sex      Age Obs_A Obs_B Obs_C  time
#  <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1 male      91 0.333 0.333 0         3
#2     2 female    88 0     0.667 0.667     3
#3     3 male      51 0.333 0.333 0         3
#4     4 female    55 0     1     0         3
```

Since you are grouping by all the character columns you don't need to include them in `across`.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned about using `regex`, an option is `matches` which can take regex compared to `starts_with` or `end_with` or `contains`.  Also, we don't need to use `ungroup` as there is an option in `summarise` to specify the `.groups` i.e. even if we use `ungroup` after `summarise`, there would be a warning message which can be avoided if we specify the `.groups`

```
library(dplyr)
TTE %>%
  group_by(id, across(where(is.character))) %>%
  summarise(Age = mean(Age), 
            across(matches('^[Oo]bs'), mean), 
            across(where(is.numeric), max), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
     id sex      Age Obs_A Obs_B Obs_C  time
  <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1 male      91 0.333 0.333 0         3
2     2 female    88 0     0.667 0.667     3
3     3 male      51 0.333 0.333 0         3
4     4 female    55 0     1     0         3
```

---

Note that the `where` is used mostly to check the values of the column and not on the column names.  For that, we need to use select-helpers